# Multiple filtering marker cluster group mapbox

Tags: javascript, filtering, cluster-computing, mapbox, markers

I am trying to use filtering marker cluster group from Mapbox.js tools. I would like to insert multiple filters in javacript code but I don't know how to make.

You can see a demo of my fiddle : 
    `enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/sduermael78/rgoxpxwq/7/

Thank you for your help.